# Moving Django models between "apps" - easy and fast

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

In my company's Django project, our models are currently spread across about 20 "app" folders with little rhyme or reason.  We'd like to consolidate them into a single new app (along with the rest of our code) so that in the future, we can refactor all parts of our system at-will without worrying about violating an "app" boundary.

Due to how Django works, simply moving the model breaks everything.  I've spent hours reading everything I can about the various proposed solutions to this problem, with the best article being:

https://realpython.com/move-django-model/

So far, I'm not happy with any of the solutions I've come across.  They're all just too onerous.

---

If I do the following:

1. Move all models to the new app.  (Let's call it "newapp".)
2. Update all references in the code to the previous locations.  (Including migration files.)
3. Take down the site for a minute.
4. Run a script to rename all database tables from `someprevapp_model` to `newapp_model`.
5. Run a script to update `app_label` for all rows in the `django_content_type` table.
6. Deploy latest codebase version, with updated model locations and references.
7. Turn site back on.

Have I succeeded, or am I missing something?

##### UPDATE

Just remembered - I'd also have to:

5.5) Run a script to update `app` for all rows in the in `django_migrations` table (easy part), and to renumber all migrations to form a single sequence (hard part), as well as modifying all migration files to match new sequence.

##### UPDATE - V2 - Full Reset

Given the need to re-sequence migrations, combined with having already been wanting to squash our huge migration stack, lead me to this new and improved recipe:

1. Move models to new app. (Let’s call it “newapp”.)
2. Delete previous migrations.
3. Update code to reflect new model locations.
4. Run makemigrations to generate single migration in new app with all models.
5. Turn site off.
6. Run script to rename my tables from prevapp_model to newapp_model.
7. Run script to update django_content_type.app_label.
8. Run script to replace contents of django_migrations with single row indicating migration newapp-0001 has already run.
9. Deploy new version.
10. Turn site back on.